# $2$ Urns, $2$ colors, pick 1 ball from each

Tags: probability

There are $2$ urns, urn $1$ contains $20$ white and $30$ red balls, urn $2$ contains $40$ white and $45$ red balls. We pick one ball from each urn, then discard $1$ of the $2$ picked balls. What is the probability, that the leftover ball is white?

All balls have equal chance to be picked and the picked ball is discarded randomly.

So far, I have only managed to calculate that chance of picking white is $2/3$ for urn $1$ and $8/9$ for urn $2$. However I'm not sure how to get probability after discarding $1$ ball.

I'm not sure how to solve this problem, could someone help me? Please explain the solution.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  What is the probability you draw White from urn $1$?  What about urn $2$?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: You have $4$ cases to consider, about the $2$ balls you pick before you discard one randomly: white from urn 1 with white from urn 2, white from urn 1 with red from urn 2, red from urn 1 with white from urn 2, and red from urn 1 with red from urn 2. What are the probability that each case happens? For each case, after discarding one ball, what is the probability that the remaining ball is white?

Comment: Notice the outcomes and probabilities are exactly the same if you first choose one urn at random, then draw one ball from just that urn. So you don't need to worry about the cases of the pair of balls and discarding one.

Comment: You get the same experiment if you choose an urn first and then draw a single ball just from this urn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not overly complicated.

The probability that the retained ball is from urn `1` is $1/2$ (likewise for urn `2`).  [Well, presuming that the discarding is made without bias.]

The probability that the ball from urn `1` is white is $20/(20+30)$ which is $2/5$, and the probability that the ball from urn `2` is white is $40/(40+45)$ which us $8/17$.

So the total probability that the retained ball is white is simply the unbiased average of those two probabilities: $(1/2)(2/5+8/17)$ which is $37/85$ .

Answer (score 2):

Computations can be much shortened (and errors minimized) as under:

On an average, we get $\frac{20}{50} = \frac25$ white ball from Urn $1$,
and $\frac{40}{85} = \frac8{17}$ white ball from urn $2$

$P[(\text{two whites})*1 + (\text{one white from any one urn})*\frac12]$

$ = \frac25\frac8{17}\cdot 1 + (\frac 25\frac 9{17}+\frac 35\frac 8{17})\cdot\frac12 = \frac{37}{85}$

Comment: How did you get 37/85? My calculator gives me 53/85.

Comment: @Anon: Typos corrected

Answer (score 0):

The probability of choosing white balls from Urn 1  is $\frac{20}{20+30}=\frac{2}{5}$ and not $\frac{2}{3}$. Similarly, the probability of choosing white balls from Urn 2  is $\frac{40}{40+45}=\frac{8}{17}$.

CASE 1. Urn 1= white, Urn 2= red. Probability of chucking the red ball out is $\frac{1}{2}$. So the total probability for case 1 is $\frac{2}{5}(1-\frac{8}{17})\frac{1}{2}=\frac{9}{85}$.

CASE 2. Urn 2= white, Urn 1= red. Probability of chucking the red ball out is $\frac{1}{2}$. So the total probability for case 1 is $\frac{8}{17}(1-\frac{2}{5})\frac{1}{2}=\frac{12}{85}$.

 CASE 3. Both Urns give white balls. Whichever ball we throw out, we always get a white ball. So the probability in this case is $\frac{8}{17}\frac{2}{5}\cdot 1=\frac{16}{85}$.

 CASE 4. Both Urns give red. Whichever ball is removed, we get red balls only. So here probability is zero.

 Final answer is $\frac{9+12+16}{85}=\frac{37}{85}$.

Comment: I see that there are computational errors in your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't CASE 2 be 12/85 and CASE 3 16/85 changing the answer to 37/85?

Comment: Sorry @Anon I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not overly complicated.

The probability that the retained ball is from urn `1` is $1/2$ (likewise for urn `2`).  [Well, presuming that the discarding is made without bias.]

So the total probability that the retained ball is white is simply the unbiased average of the probabilities of drawing a white ball from the urns:

$$\mathsf P(W)=\tfrac 12\big(\mathsf P(W\mid U_1) + \mathsf P(W\mid U_2)\big)$$

---

Although your calculations when awry

The probability that the ball from urn `1` is white is $20/(20+30)$ which is $2/5$, and the probability that the ball from urn `2` is white is $40/(40+45)$ which us $8/17$.

Answer (score -1):

See this diagram for visual understanding
[image]

To find probability for "white leftover".

> "Urn-2 discarded, white leftover" + "Urn 1 discarded, white leftover" =  $\frac{20}{100} + \frac{40}{190} = 0.41$.

Answer (score -1):

See this diagram for visual understanding
[image]

To find probability for "white leftover".

> "Urn-2 discarded, white leftover" + "Urn 1 discarded, white leftover" =  $\frac{20}{100} + \frac{40}{190} = 0.41$.